# How to exclude your own app from the Share menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-intent, share

The app has an intent filter to allow it to appear in the share menu in other applications via ACTION_SEND intents.  The app itself also has a share menu using ACTION_SEND and createChooser(), and my app appears in the list.  Since they are already in my app it seems strange to have them be able to share back to itself.

Is there a way for my app not to appear in the list if it's being called from my app?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#excluding-specific-targets-by-component

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way for my app not to appear in the list if it's being called from my app?

Not via `createChooser()`. You can create your own chooser-like dialog via `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` and filter yourself out that way, though.

Comment: This there something built in that I can feed my filtered List<ResolveInfo> back into, to create the Share Dialog, or do I have to create my own dialog using the list?  If it's the latter how do you get the App's icons to appear in a dialog?  Thanks.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: You would use you own dialog (e.g., `AlertDialog.Builder` and `setAdapter()`). `PackageManager` can give you the icons. See http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot/

Comment: thank you that's really helpful.  Do you have any suggestions which is the best way to compare/filter the list returned from queryIntentActivities() against my app?  I was thinking to use the package name, but is there a better comparison?

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: Package name is almost assuredly your best option.

Answer (score 22):

Here goes your solution. If you want to exclude your own app you can change "packageNameToExclude" with ctx.getPackageName()

```
public static Intent shareExludingApp(Context ctx, String packageNameToExclude, String imagePath, String text) {
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = ctx.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(createShareIntent(text,new File(imagePath)), 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            Intent targetedShare = createShareIntent(text,new File(imagePath));

            if (!info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageNameToExclude)) {
                targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
            }
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0),
                "Select app to share");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
        return chooserIntent;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Intent createShareIntent(String text, File file) {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    if (text != null) {
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    return share;
}
```

Comment: This is working for me .. just I have a question about this targetedShareIntents.remove(0) ... why did you do that ?

Comment: Because you need to give one intent to the Chooser creator method and then add the rest of intents as an extra

Comment: Doesn't work. It shows up strange share targets and several apps don't appear in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(new Intent(), "Select app to share");
```

Answer (score 1):

Already Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131607/7764015

After updating targetSdkVersion to 31 the older solution will stop working.
This below solution will work for all android version

**In Manifest file AndroidManidest.xml**

(In Android api 31 by default queryIntentActivities() will return empty list to get the desired result from queryIntentActivities you need to add the below query parameter in manifest file.)

```
<manifest>
   <queries>
      <intent>
         <!--Change the action and data depending on you share intent-->
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 
         <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>

      </intent>
   </queries>
</manifest>
```

**In the activity file share function**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Link");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Description")

ArrayList<ComponentName> excludedComponents = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packageManager.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0)){
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
//change facebook with whichever app you want to exclude or you can directly search for the specific package name
   if (packageName.contains("facebook")){
   excludedComponents.add(new 
   ComponentName(packageName,resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
   }
}

Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share");
intentChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EXCLUDE_COMPONENTS, excludedComponents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(intentChooser);
```