# Excluding activity types in react native share on Android

Tags: android, react-native, share

According to the react native docs, excluding activity types for the share module is only available on IOS - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html.  I'm trying to exclude email/sms for analytics purposes.  Is there a way to circumvent this limitation or is this just not possible in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a react native module. Keep in mind that using this solution requires you having a keyword of the app's package name that you want to exclude.

Here is my native module:

```
package com.testproject;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShareModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public ShareModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ShareExample";
    }

    private static boolean containsOneWord(String word, ReadableArray keywords) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i++)
            if (word.contains(keywords.getString(i))) return true;
        return false;
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void share(String subject, String message, ReadableArray toExclude) {

        List<Intent> shareIntentsLists = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = getCurrentActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        if (!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
                String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                if (!containsOneWord(packageName.toLowerCase(), toExclude)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                    intent.setPackage(packageName);
                    shareIntentsLists.add(intent);
                }
            }
            if (!shareIntentsLists.isEmpty()) {
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntentsLists.remove(0), "Choose app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, shareIntentsLists.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                getCurrentActivity().startActivity(chooserIntent);
            } else
                Log.e("Error", "No Apps can perform your task");

        }

    }
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules.ShareExample.share('Hi', 'Hello world', ['mms', 'sms', 'messa', 'gm', 'mail', 'text']);
```

Keep in mind that different sms and email apps may have no keywords in common so include as much as you can.

For instructions on how to add a native module check the react native documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html).

References:

- [How to exclude a specific application from ACTION_SEND Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345994/how-to-exclude-a-specific-application-from-action-send-intent)