# How to prevent application from sharing images to itself?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, file-sharing, event-receiver

**Problem:**
I'm seeing my own app in the device's app chooser when sharing an image from within my app.

[image]

I'm working on a photo app that will allow users to share their edited images using an Intent.ACTION_SEND with the device's application chooser by starting the chooser activity from an Intent.createChooser. Within my AndroidManifest.xml file I have declared a provider.

I'm also allowing other applications to launch my application by sharing images and selecting my app in the device's chooser activity. Within the AndroidManifest.xml the activity has an intent-filter with android.intent.action.SEND as the action.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testcom.mypicapp">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyPicApp">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.testcom.mypicapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                />
        </provider>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyPicAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's the code I'm using to share the edited image:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
shareIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareUri );
shareIntent.setType( "image/png" );
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(  shareIntent, "Share My Pic App Image" );
startActivityForResult( chooser, SHARE_RESPONSE_CODE );
```

**Question:**
So how would I prevent my app showing in the application chooser that my application started, while being included in other app's application chooser? Is there a way to exclude my application, perhaps adding an extra in the intent to start the application chooser?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here's another similar question asked: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345994/how-to-exclude-a-specific-application-from-action-send-intent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent-and-set-a-different-text-for)

Comment: @AkakiKapanadze thank you.  I was able to find a great solution from following the examples you provided.